# HTTP/1.1" 405 0 Django - Unable to go past Login Page

Tags: django, forms, http, post, http-status-code-405

I created a login page and I have users with 3 roles, Administrator, Student, Supervisor. Each of these users have their separate dashboards. When I login using the username and password, it should check the user's group and based on which should redirect the user to their respective dashboard. When I hit the submit button to login, it gives me an error

`.   HTTP/1.1" 405 0

```
 Request URL:
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 Request Method:
 POST
 Status Code:
 405 Method Not Allowed

 Remote Address:
 127\.0.0.1:8000
 Referrer Policy:
 strict-origin-when-cross-origin
 Allow:
 GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
 Connection:
 close
 Content-Type:
 text/html; charset=utf-8
 Date:
 Thu, 17 Aug 2023 23:48:51 GMT
 Server:
 WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.3
```

`
The unfortunate part is that the home page allows only GET requests. Not sure how to change this. I manually forced my app to use post requests by defining them in views.py and forced post request on the form in the home.html file which I use to load my login page. So if you can review the code and help me get past this, it would be of great help.

The name of my project is webappsretake2023 and the name of the app is spmsapp

spmsapp/views.py

```
     from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
     from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
     from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
     from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
     from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
     from spmsapp.models import ProjectProposal, ProjectTopic
     from register.models import CustomUser
     from register.forms import UserRegistrationForm

     def home(request):
     return render(request, 'home.html')

     @require_POST
     def home(request):
     print("Received request with method:", request.method)
     form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
     username = form.cleaned_data\['username'\]
     password = form.cleaned_data\['password'\]
     user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
     if user is not None:
     login(request, user)
     return redirect('dashboard')  # Redirect to appropriate dashboard
     else:
     \# Handle authentication error
     error_message = 'Invalid credentials'
     else:
     error_message = None

     return render(request, 'spmsapp/home.html', {'form': form, 'error_message': error_message})

     @login_required
def administrator_dashboard(request):
if request.user.roles.filter(role='Administrator').exists():
\# Fetch data or perform actions specific to administrators
users = CustomUser.objects.all()
topics = ProjectTopic.objects.all()
return render(request, 'spmsapp/dashboard/administrator_dashboard.html', {'users': users, 'topics': topics})
else:
return render(request, 'error.html', {'message': 'You are not authorized to access this page.'})

@login_required
def supervisor_dashboard(request):
if request.user.roles.filter(role='Supervisor').exists():
\# Fetch data or perform actions specific to supervisors
\# For example, fetch project proposals assigned to this supervisor
proposals = ProjectProposal.objects.filter(supervisor=request.user)
return render(request, 'spmsapp/dashboard/supervisor_dashboard.html', {'proposals': proposals})
else:
return render(request, 'error.html', {'message': 'You are not authorized to access this page.'})

@login_required
def student_dashboard(request):
if request.user.roles.filter(role='Student').exists():
\# Fetch data or perform actions specific to students
\# For example, fetch project proposals available for selection
proposals = ProjectProposal.objects.filter(accepted=False)
return render(request, 'spmsapp/dashboard/student_dashboard.html', {'proposals': proposals})
else:
return render(request, 'error.html', {'message': 'You are not authorized to access this page.'})
```

templates/spmsapp/home.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>



  
  
  SPMS App - Home
  
  




  <h2>Welcome to SPMS App</h2>
  
  
    <h2>Login</h2>
    
      {% csrf_token %}
      
        Username:
        <br>
      
      
      
        Password:
        <br>
      
      
      
        
      
    
    {% if error_message %}
    
      {{ error_message }}
    
    {% endif %}
```

spmsapp/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = \[
path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='spmsapp/home.html'), name='login'),
path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
path('administrator/', views.administrator_dashboard, name='administrator_dashboard'),
path('student/', views.student_dashboard, name='student_dashboard'),
path('supervisor/', views.supervisor_dashboard, name='supervisor_dashboard'),
\# Other URL patterns can be added here
\]
```

The entire Code: https://github.com/ChristopherSunith/webappsretake2023

Comment: Why you passing request in `authenticate` ? It should be passed if you are defining an authentication method

Comment: The request parameter is passed to authenticate mainly for security reasons, as some authentication backends might rely on information from the request to perform the authentication process securely. For example, certain authentication methods might take into account the user's IP address, user agent, or other request-related details to enhance security. 
The request object contains information about the incoming HTTP request. It can include headers, cookies, user agent, and more. Some authentication methods might need this information for security checks.